# DjangoのTextFieldで1行あたりの最大文字数を設定したい

Tags: python, python3, django

お世話になっております
Django、Python初心者です

文章のデータを保存するためにmodelでTextFieldを定義しているのですが
HTML側で文章を表示する都合で、サーバーにデータを保存するにあたり、
1行あたり最大20文字で、最大文字数を超える場合は改行されて次の行に入力にするように
フィールドにバリデーションを設けることができないかと考えています

この条件を満たす可能な方法がありましたら、是非ご教授いただきたいです
また、文章が保存できるのであれば別のフィールドの型でもかまいません
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1):

バリデーターをつくればいいのではないですかね。

[Django Documentation - バリデータを記述する](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.1/ref/validators/)